# make an orthonormal basis with complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to make an orthonormal basis of the subspace spanned by${(1,i,1-i),(0,2,-1-i)}$

and im not sure how to do this with complex vectors.

edit: the inner product is the standard complex inner product

Comment: Apply the Gramm-Schmidht method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know how your inner product is defined. Then  vectors $u,v $ are orhogonal in this space iff $<u,v>=0$.

Use Gram-Schmidt ortogonalisation algorithm. Take the first to be $w_1=\frac {u}{\sqrt {<u,u>}}$. The second ortogonal vector is then $w_2=v-<v,w_1>w_1$. And make this a unit.

Comment: the inner product is the standard complex inner product